# ReadToEndAsync from UI Thread

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

If I call await ReadToEndAsync  from the UI thread on Windows Phone 8, on what context will ReadToEndAsync do its work? Will a task get queued for processing by the UI thread itself, or will a new thread do the work.

Based on this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/04/asynchrony-in-c-5-0-part-four-it-s-not-magic.aspx

it seems like it will run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an essential truth of `async` in its purest form: There is no thread.

For a truly asynchronous stream, `ReadToEndAsync` has no almost work to do. When you call that method, it merely asks the runtime to read to the end, and notify it when the operation is complete (via a `Task`). The runtime turns to the OS, asks it to read, and notify it when the operation is complete (e.g., via an IOCP). The OS turns to the device driver, asks it to read, and notify it when the operation is complete (e.g., via an IRP). The device driver turns to the device, asks it to read, and notify it when the operation is complete (e.g., via an IRQ).

There is no thread.

This is an ideal situation, of course. In the real world, at some point the "read to end" operation is broken up into several "read n byte" operations, and those need to be stitched back together. That (tiny) amount of work is done using borrowed threads: unknowable threads for kernel-mode code and thread pool threads for user-mode code.

Also, there are some situations where an asynchronous API does not exist. In those cases, asynchronous work is faked using a thread pool thread. For example, if you call `ReadToEndAsync` on a `MemoryStream`, there are no asynchronous APIs for reading from memory, so that is a fake asynchronous operation that will run on the thread pool.

But the idea that there always must be a thread to execute an asynchronous operation is not the truth. Do not try to control the thread — that's impossible. Instead, only try to realize the truth: there is no thread.

**Edit:** Expanded this answer [into a blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: Thank you Neo...I mean Stephen.  Correct me if I'm wrong, so what this means is that no matter how long this process takes, it has no impact on the UI thread since work is being done at the OS level.  But when the work completes, the code under the await statement will be executed back on the UI thread/context?

Comment: Yes. In this case, the code after the `await` will automatically return to the UI thread. I explain this more precisely in [my async/await intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).