# Clarification needed on async and await

Tags: c#, async-await

I read many articles on async and await(mostly from msdn - which is good actually). There is still one question that bothers me and I could not find the answer.

If there is an await statement on a task then the control is returned to its caller until it is awaited again in the caller. In that case is this time consuming task getting executed in a separate thread? If not then how is it getting executed parallel to the main thread.

```
async Task<string> GetContentsAsync()
{
    int sample = 0;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Task<string> contents = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");
            
    string data = await contents;
    return data;
}
```

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Can you provide an example (code) to describe your question better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ReadToEndAsync from UI Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323946/readtoendasync-from-ui-thread)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In that case is this time consuming task getting executed in a separate thread?

There are two kinds of tasks. Some `Task`s have code to execute, and they run on some thread. Other `Task`s do *not* execute code; they just represent some future event.

The "event tasks" are used a *lot* by `async`, particularly in I/O scenarios. In your example, you're executing an HTTP GET. `GetStringAsync` will send the HTTP request and then return an "event task" that completes when the response is received. While the HTTP request is in flight and being processed by the server, there's no *code* for the client to execute for that request. So there's no thread required, and none is used.

Also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323946/readtoendasync-from-ui-thread/16324769#16324769).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how the task is created, but no, tasks are not *inherently* executed on a separate thread automatically. Some helper methods, like `Task.Run` for example, can help you make sure a task is put on a separate thread (the thread pool in this case).

Remember that a GUI application, let's say WinForms specifically, runs a so-called *event loop*. In WinForms this happens behind your back, in the `Application.Run` call. This event loop receives events like clicks and invokes your handlers. The thread that this loop executes on is referred to as "the GUI thread". In WinForms, it's the thread that creates all the controls, and hence also the only thread allowed to touch those controls.

When you create a task using the `async` modifier on a method, that code is also scheduled to execute via this event loop. It's just queued up. Just like the good old `Invoke` calls. So once your event handler returns, eventually the event loop gets to that queued up task, executes it, and then executes the rest of the method that followed the `await`. No parallelism here.

However, there are other ways to create tasks; calling an `async` method is just one way. `Task.Run` creates tasks that are put on separate threads. `GetStringAsync` you show in your example will actually run in parallel with whichever thread invoked the task.

Comment: If I dont explicitly use Task.Run in that case how is it executed?

Comment: In the sample code I have provided How would the execution be?

Comment: *orthogonal to parallelism*? <blink>

Comment: @Liam damn, that paragraph didn't fit with the flow so I deleted it, but yes. Orthogonal to parallelism. I'd like to address that elsewhere but in the context of this question it doesn't really make sense :) If you ask that separately I'll address it there.

Comment: I have never in my 32 years heard of the word orthogonal, though my Ancient Greek is a bit rusty ;) I will now, after Googling it, use it as much as I can......

Comment: @romkyns:I think I am able to comprehend your answer, but the event loop does run in a thread right?

Comment: @Liam I just meant that whether you use async or not, and whether you use parallelism or not, are independent concepts. Try it; create an async button handler, another async method that modifies the GUI, and await the latter from the former. You'll see that all methods here will execute on the GUI thread. With zero parallelism, but using async.

Comment: @ckv yes, it runs in a thread - that one important thread that's known as the "GUI thread"; the only thread allowed to modify the UI controls.